# Initialize ofvideograbber without grabFrame -OpenFrameworks

Tags: openframeworks

I sent some OpenFrameworks code to another computer which has a later version of OF downloaded. when I try to run this code in order to open and start the video grabber it doesn't recognize `movie.grabFrame()`. I tried `movie.update()` aswell and that does not start the video either. Does anyone know what the latest version uses instead of the following code:

```
 movie.grabFrame();  
        //do we have a new frame?  
        if (movie.isFrameNew()){  
            colorImg.setFromPixels(movie.getPixels(),w,h);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.8.0, the equivalent of `.grabFrame()` is `.update()`.

If your issue is that the movie isn't starting, make sure you're calling `.play()` on it.

The naming of your variables is a bit confusing though. An ofVideoGrabber is for getting video data from a live source, such as a webcam. Calling your vidGrabber `movie` implies that it's actually an ofVideoPlayer?

Comment: Okay sorry that is confusing. It's an instance of ofvideograbber. Will change it to cam